# Why is my SQL update using a CASE statement creating null values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I'm running the script below to update values in one column based on the value of another column in the same table. After running it, I did notice that the values for the columns in the `CASE` statement did update fine, BUT all of the other columns that should not have been included were and were changed to NULL...  How did this happen?

```
UPDATE configsystem 
SET field1 = CASE
                 WHEN field2 =  32 THEN 0
                 WHEN field1 =  67 THEN 0
                 WHEN field1 =  99 THEN 1
                 WHEN field1 = 102 THEN 0
                 WHEN field1 = 105 THEN 5
             END
WHERE 1 = 1
```

See above - I ran the script expecting the values that needed updated were and then the rest of the fields that weren't in the `CASE` statement would not be updated in any way(but indeed they were and set to NULL)

Slight update from testing: I did remove the 'where' clause and that didn't cause a change in results(wasn't expecting it to). Not sure why an ELSE clause would be needed but, perhaps that's part of the cause?

Comment: Add `ELSE field1 = field1` to you case _expression_. Or, even better, add a WHERE clause.

Comment: BTW, note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: You don't have an ELSE block on your CASE expression. So, implicitly, it is ELSE NULL. As you're updating every record (as dictated by the WHERE clause), a lot of rows are hitting that implicit ELSE NULL.

Comment: T-SQL `CASE` is an expression rather than a statement.  Your `UPDATE` statement updates every row and the `CASE` expression returns a value for each row. If the column value of the row isn't matched by a `WHEN` clause, the result will be `NULL` unless you specify an `ELSE`  to assign a different value.

Answer (score 0):

Only UPDATE the desired rows.

```
UPDATE configsystem SET field1 =  
CASE
WHEN field2  = 32 THEN 0
WHEN field1  =  67 THEN 0
WHEN field1  =  99 THEN 1
WHEN field1  =  102 THEN 0
WHEN field1  =  105 THEN 5
END
WHERE field2  = 32 or field1 in (67, 99, 102, 105)
```

Answer (score 0):

Else field1 must be it, set it to itself, if you want to be sure.